# Amazon Simple DB select from domain with period in name

Tags: amazon-simpledb

In amazon simpleDB I am using the customer name as a bucket name template.
buckname = com.mycompany.projectname.customerId as the simpledb domain name.

The domain is created sucessfully, however, using the simpledb select API to do

`select * from com.mycompany.projectname.customerId`

I receive the 400 error:

```
AWS Error Code: InvalidQueryExpression, AWS Error Message: 
The specified query expression syntax is not valid.
```

Can this select statement be escaped somehow, or should we use an alternate domain naming strategy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enclose domain name between acute i.e (`). Try to run this query :

```
select * from `com.mycompany.projectname.customerId`
```